# Link css/js file in different .war

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

I have a file in

> carrier.war/web/index.jsp

from that file i have to refer to the location

> common.war/web/css/test.css

i used the following coding

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<%=host %>/common/css/test.css" />
```

The file is not loading, i checked in the network. I am getting 404 error. I put in the same .war and checked its loading. Same like this i have a js file also.
Can anyone help me with this? am i using the wrong method or do i have to correct something?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Should `href="<%=host %>/common/css/test.css"` be `href="<%=host %>/common.war/web/css/test.css"` maybe?

Comment: No, still same problem. it's not getting the file @ViperCode

Comment: are you able to navigate to the css file in your browser? If so what's the url? example.com/css/test.css or something similar?

Comment: i am getting sample.dev//common/css/test.css @ViperCode

Comment: `href="/common/css/test.css"` I haven't worked with a .war before so I'm not quite sure how the folder structure is different. If that still fails just try putting the full url that you just found into the href and see if that works `href="sample.dev/common/css/test.css"`

Comment: no its not working, this can be used if the file in the same .war location @ViperCode

Comment: Are you using port 80 in this environment?

Comment: ya i used like that @Tap , i figure out the problem. i have to change my sever stetting. The problem is with the server setting not with the **coding**